# Flask and Jinja2 with bleach, image HTML not working

Tags: python, html, flask, markdown, jinja2

I have been creating a small blog for myself for a project, only I, as the user, can access the posting page. I had previously been following a Flask tutorial, the end product of which enables you to post HTML and pass it through the Jinja2 templating, using bleach and Markdown.

In my `models.py` file, these are the allowed tags.

```
@staticmethod

def on_changed_body(target, value, oldvalue, initiator):
    allowed_tags = ['a', 'abbr', 'acronym', 'b', 'blockquote', 'code',
                    'em', 'i', 'li', 'ol', 'pre', 'strong', 'ul',
                    'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'p', 'img', 'video', 'div', 'iframe', 'p', 'br', 'span', 'hr', 'src', 'class']
    target.body_html = bleach.linkify(bleach.clean(
        markdown(value, output_format='html'),
        tags=allowed_tags, strip=False))
```

I have added some img and embedding tags, as these are important to my blog. I have an example post consisting of some text and an image, which is being saved to the (SQLAlchemy MySQL) database exactly how I have written it. Below is taken straight from the database.

```
<p>Hello</p>

<img src="https://catastrophicfindings.files.wordpress.com/2012/07/moomin-childhood-memories-260482_829_494.jpg">

<marquee>Bye</marquee>
```

Also, I have a field below my blog post form that displays a preview of the HTML. The image appears as intended, so I know this is fine, and the `<marquee></marquee>` tag appears as markup.

In my template file, I am passing this body_html like so.

```
{% if post.body_html %}
    {{ post.body_html | safe }}
{% else %}
    {{ post.body }}
{% endif %}
```

When I then navigate to the post in my browser, the image does not appear at all. However the marquee tag appears as `<marquee>Bye</marquee>`, and on further inspection in the developer console, an `<img>` tag is appearing in the HTML, just without the 'src' attribute.

Is there any way to fix this? Would this be something in the configuration of Jinja? Is there a way to declare allowed attributes, if this was the solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

A little more patience and some googling proved fruitful, taken straight from the [bleach docs](http://bleach.readthedocs.org/en/latest/clean.html):

> The attributes kwarg is a whitelist of attributes. It can be a list, in which case the attributes are allowed for any tag, or a dictionary, in which case the keys are tag names (or a wildcard: * for all tags) and the values are lists of allowed attributes.

So, I added a dict of desired attributes into my bleach.clean function in `models.py`:

```
 @staticmethod
    def on_changed_body(target, value, oldvalue, initiator):
        allowed_tags = ['a', 'abbr', 'acronym', 'b', 'blockquote', 'code',
                        'em', 'i', 'li', 'ol', 'pre', 'strong', 'ul',
                        'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'p', 'img', 'video', 'div', 'iframe', 'p', 'br', 'span', 'hr', 'src', 'class']
        allowed_attrs = {'*': ['class'],
                        'a': ['href', 'rel'],
                        'img': ['src', 'alt']}
        target.body_html = bleach.linkify(bleach.clean(
            markdown(value, output_format='html'),
            tags=allowed_tags, strip=False, attributes=allowed_attrs))
```

And this works fantastically. I will be adjusting it to accommodate embedding also.

Comment: You might want to check out bleach-whitelist which is "a curated list of tags, attributes, and styles suitable for filtering user-provided HTML using bleach." <https://github.com/yourcelf/bleach-whitelist>